# How can I reverse the order of this structure?

Tags: python

How can I reverse the order of these items?

```
L = []
items = [4,3],[1,2]
L.append(items)
## reverse the order of items in L such that L contains : [([1,2],[4,3])]
```

Reverse the order of items in L such that L contains : [([1,2],[4,3])]

Comment: Have a look at [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) in python, `items[::-1]`

Comment: `[tuple(reversed(L[0]))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
items = [4,3],[1,2]
L = items[::-1]
print(L) # output[([1,2], [4,3])]
```

Comment: Your solution prints `([1, 2], [4, 3])` and not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You can flip each tuple by:

```
L = [(b, a) for a, b in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `reversed()` to reverse the order of elements in the array:

```
L = []
items = [4,3],[1,2]
L.append(items)

L = [tuple(reversed(i)) for i in L]
# [([1, 2], [4, 3])]
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
L = [(i[1], i[0]) for i in L]
```

or

```
L = [(L[0][1], L[0][0])]
```